# Are specific generic conversion operators supported by the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, implicit-conversion

As you may know, it's impossible to declare non-generic conversion operators of a generic Type in C#:

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public static implicit operator T(Generic<T> value) // legal
    { return default(T); }
    public static implicit operator Generic<T>(T value) // legal
    { return new Generic<T>(); }
    public static implicit operator Generic<int>(int value) // illegal
    { return new Generic<int>(); }
}
```

Is that a framework limitation or would it be possible to insert such declarations into an assembly and then consume them from C# and/or other .NET languages?

---

For context:

I'm working on a code generation library that heavily relies on following a specification in the most statically typesafe way possible (essentially replicating the API in C# but deferring all operations). However, many of the expression types have analogues in the .NET Framework that could be inserted as constants. To minimise friction those types should be usable anywhere the analogous deferred types are required.

Currently I can think of a few possible solution of varying quality:

- Generate a few dozen derived types to represent various levels of array nesting.

  - Pros: typesafe, (almost) completely seamless for the consumer.
  - Cons: likely really annoying to implement (in comparison), slightly hacky generic API
- Generate a few dozen extension methods for the conversions.

  - Pros: typesafe, seamless generic API
  - Cons: usually not seamless, possibly relatively annoying to implement
- Implement the operator generically and do type checking at runtime.

  - Pros: seamless, generically seamless
  - Cons: **not statically typesafe**, hacky in a bad way

Right now I'd probably go for the generated types if I can't shoehorn the proper operators into my assembly somehow.

Comment: I would consider a "compiler limitation" or "language limitation" rather than a framework limitation. Consider that if those were methods they would all be perfectly legal. Which one would be chosen in a particular situation is up to the compiler's overload resolution rules. You could probably emit IL equivalent to your example and have a perfectly valid assembly, but I doubt the API would consumable via C#.